# what is the difference between ubuntu openstack and openstack kilo to build a private cloud?

Tags: ubuntu, cloud, openstack

I am trying to build a private cloud.

I was wondering what is the difference between

ubuntu openstack using maas to build the machines
http://www.ubuntu.com/cloud/ubuntu-openstack

which have some heavy prerequisites.

And openstack kilo and it's previous versions https://www.openstack.org/software/kilo/

which have no explicit prerequisites.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, since OpenStack is an open-source project, many groups try to "sell" their own ready-to-use implementation. If you want to install Kilo, you will have to install all of the components separately. So it probably takes longer, the difference is you know what to install and you can have your custom version.

Following a more "ready-to-use" solution such as Ubuntu is probably easier and you also know that if you do follow blindy the instructions, it should work (but of course, the pre-requisites are to only work with Ubuntu technos ;) )

Other thing about MAAS, it's the same concept as cloud computing (provisionning machines when you need them) but with physical servers, so of course, you are going to need some heavy infrastructure. As for the classical Kilo implementation, 3 servers are enough (controller, network and compute node)

But in the end, installing the ubuntu solution is the same as installing Kilo on your own (Kilo is the the name of OpenStack's last version so the ubuntu solution most-likely uses Kilo too or the older one, Juno, not sure about this).

There you have it, I would recommend follwing the installation guide on how to install Kilo on an Ubuntu envrionment, you can find it here: http://docs.openstack.org/kilo/install-guide/install/apt/content/index.html

Comment: First thanks for your response. But let me get something straight what do u mean by the pre-quisities are to only work with ubuntu technos, does this pre-requisties are not actually needed?

Comment: MAAS is property of Ubuntu, so using it means using Ubuntu. It's not needed to work with MAAS, this is just one of the ways to install OpenStack. If you want to know the "minimal" needed, you can find it here: http://docs.openstack.org/kilo/install-guide/install/apt/content/ch_basic_environment.html#basics-prerequisites
If you don't want to use MAAS, it's fine, you can just follow the guide to install OpenStack on an Ubuntu environment on 3 nodes (even works on virtualization). Hope it's clear now ;)